# Override UITextView's CMD + Z key command

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, mac-catalyst

Is it possible to override `UITextView`'s handling of `cmd + z` and `cmd + shift + z` ?

I've tried to

- override the `keyCommand` property, but the selectors are never called..
- override the `undoManager`, this doesn't help either

```swift
class CustomTextView: UITextView {

    override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]? {
       [
            // cmd + z (doesn't work)
            UIKeyCommand(input: "z", modifierFlags: [.command], action: #selector(undo)),
                
            // cmd + shift + z  (doesn't work)
            UIKeyCommand(input: "z", modifierFlags: [.command, .shift], action: #selector(redo)),
                
            // z (works)
            UIKeyCommand(input: "z", modifierFlags: [], action: #selector(z)),
        ]
    }
     
    // this doesn't help   
    override var undoManager: UndoManager? { return nil }
        






    // undo
    @objc private func undo() {
        print("undo")
    }

    // redo
    @objc private func redo() {
        print("redo")
    }

    // z
    @objc private func z() {
        print("z")
    }   
}
```

Comment: Feedback submitted: FB9111541

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a **UITextView+UIResponder.swift** extension:

```
import UIKit

extension UITextView {
    static var myUndoManager = UndoManager()

    fileprivate func handleUndo () { ... }
    fileprivate func handleRedo () { ... }

    override var undoManager : UndoManager? {
        return Self.myUndoManager
    }

    override func pressesBegan (
        _ presses: Set<UIPress>
      , with event: UIPressesEvent?
    )
    {
        for press in presses {
            guard
                let key = press.key
              , key.charactersIgnoringModifiers == "z"
            else { continue }

            switch key.modifierFlags {
                case .command:
                    handleUndo()
                case [ .command, .shift]:
                    handleRedo()
                default:
                    break
            }
        }
        super.pressesBegan (
            presses
          , with: event
        )
    }
}
```

Relevant Apple References:

[UIResponder::`func pressesBegan(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621134-pressesbegan)
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder

[Keyboards & Input::`class UIKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikey)
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikey

See Also: [uiresponder](/questions/tagged/uiresponder)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uiresponder

#### Why won't overriding `keyCommands` work?

UITextView is opaque, so I can't see for myself , but I think it overrides `pressesBegan(_:with:)` and does not call `super` for any key-press it handles.  Without that call to `super`, `UIPressesEvent` events never propagate up the responder chain; `keyCommands` will never see them.

Comment: Nice Answer! But this will disable the repeating for key Commands, is there a way to preserve it?

Comment: You could start a Timer in pressesBegan then invalidate and stop the Timer in pressesEnded

Comment: @HassanTaleb I'm not sure what is meant by "repeating"; is your intent to only carve-out UITextView's Undo/Redo responsibilities & keep everything else it handles untouched ( which is not my interpretation of the OP's question)?  If so, then you'll need to subclass UITextView properly, and adapt my answer such that it only calls super.pressesBegan(_:with:) when User intent is to do something *other* than Undo/Redo.  If you post such a question, I'll be happy to answer it.

Comment: By repetition I mean the buttons (CMD + z) stay pressed, and the func "handle Undo()" recalled repetitively @Jason

Comment: @HassanTaleb youjin's suggestion seems good:  add a static Timer to the extension, set it using Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval:repeats:block:) from within `handleUndo()`, implement pressesChanged/Ended/Cancelled such that they all invalidate the static timer.